# How to send an SMS from Debian command line?

Tags: networking, debian, modem, wwan

I have a 4G wwan modem (Fibocom L850GL) with a valid SIM card on a Debian PC. 
I have `modem-manager-gui` and I can send SMS with it.

[image: modem manager gui help send SMS from linux with a GUI]

How can I do the same from the command line?

I have tried with mmcli v1.10.0 but I have

```
dka@dka:[~]: mmcli -m 0 --messaging-create-sms="text='Hello world',number='+33692822789'"
Successfully created new SMS: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SMS/0
dka@dka:[~]: mmcli -s 0 --send -v
[28 Nov 2019, 03:46:12] [Debug] Assuming '0' is the SMS index
[28 Nov 2019, 03:46:12] [Debug] ModemManager process found at ':1.8'
[28 Nov 2019, 03:46:12] [Debug] Sms found at '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SMS/0'

error: couldn't send the SMS: 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.libmbim.Error.Status.Failure: Couldn't send SMS part: Failure'
```

I just did with `mmcli -G DEBUG` as stated in `mmcli` [documentation](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/how-tos-and-troubleshooting/debugging-3g/modem-debugging-with-mmcli), this is the log:

```
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Received message...#012>>>>>> RAW:#012>>>>>>   length = 52#012>>>>>>   data   = 07:00:00:80:34:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:53:3F:BE:EB:14:FE:44:67:9F:90:33:A2:23:E5:6C:3F:05:00:00:00:08:00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:00:00:00
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Received message (translated)...#012>>>>>> Header:#012>>>>>>   length      = 52#012>>>>>>   type        = indicate-status (0x80000007)#012>>>>>>   transaction = 0#012>>>>>> Fragment header:#012>>>>>>   total   = 1#012>>>>>>   current = 0#012>>>>>> Contents:#012>>>>>>   service = 'sms' (533fbeeb-14fe-4467-9f90-33a223e56c3f)#012>>>>>>   cid     = 'message-store-status' (0x00000005)#012>>>>>> Fields:#012>>>>>>   Flag = 'new-message'#012>>>>>>   MessageIndex = '1'
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug> Received notification (service 'sms', command 'message-store-status')
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug> Received SMS store status update: 'new-message'
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug> Reading new SMS at index '1'
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Sent message...#012<<<<<< RAW:#012<<<<<<   length = 60#012<<<<<<   data   = 03:00:00:00:3C:00:00:00:32:00:00:00:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:53:3F:BE:EB:14:FE:44:67:9F:90:33:A2:23:E5:6C:3F:02:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0C:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:00:00:00
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Sent message (translated)...#012<<<<<< Header:#012<<<<<<   length      = 60#012<<<<<<   type        = command (0x00000003)#012<<<<<<   transaction = 50#012<<<<<< Fragment header:#012<<<<<<   total   = 1#012<<<<<<   current = 0#012<<<<<< Contents:#012<<<<<<   service = 'sms' (533fbeeb-14fe-4467-9f90-33a223e56c3f)#012<<<<<<   cid     = 'read' (0x00000002)#012<<<<<<   type    = 'query' (0x00000000)#012<<<<<< Fields:#012<<<<<<   Format = 'pdu'#012<<<<<<   Flag = 'index'#012<<<<<<   MessageIndex = '1'
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Received message...#012>>>>>> RAW:#012>>>>>>   length = 112#012>>>>>>   data   = 03:00:00:80:70:00:00:00:32:00:00:00:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:53:3F:BE:EB:14:FE:44:67:9F:90:33:A2:23:E5:6C:3F:02:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:40:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:00:00:00:10:00:00:00:30:00:00:00:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:10:00:00:00:20:00:00:00:07:91:33:96:05:00:56:F4:20:0B:91:33:96:85:62:87:F9:00:00:91:21:10:61:33:81:40:05:F4:F2:9C:2E:03
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Received message (translated)...#012>>>>>> Header:#012>>>>>>   length      = 112#012>>>>>>   type        = command-done (0x80000003)#012>>>>>>   transaction = 50#012>>>>>> Fragment header:#012>>>>>>   total   = 1#012>>>>>>   current = 0#012>>>>>> Contents:#012>>>>>>   status error = 'None' (0x00000000)#012>>>>>>   service      = 'sms' (533fbeeb-14fe-4467-9f90-33a223e56c3f)#012>>>>>>   cid          = 'read' (0x00000002)#012>>>>>> Fields:#012>>>>>>   Format = '0'#012>>>>>>   MessagesCount = '1'#012>>>>>>   PduMessages = '{#012>>>>>>     [0] = {#012>>>>>>           MessageIndex = '1'#012>>>>>>           MessageStatus = '0'#012>>>>>>           PduData = '07:91:33:96:05:00:56:f4:20:0b:91:33:96:85:62:87:f9:00:00:91:21:10:61:33:81:40:05:f4:f2:9c:2e:03'#012>>>>>>     },#012>>>>>>   }'#012>>>>>>   CdmaMessages = 
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug> Parsing PDU (1)...
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug>   SMSC address parsed: '+3369500****'
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug>   Deliver type PDU detected
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug>   Number parsed: '+336********'
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug>   PID: 0
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug>   user data encoding is GSM7
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug>   user data length: 5 elements
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug>   user data length: 5 bytes
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug> Decoding SMS text with '5' elements
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug> Converting SMS part text from GSM-7 to UTF-8...
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug>    Got UTF-8 text: 'test2'
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug> Correctly parsed PDU (1)
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug> SMS part at 'mt/1' is from a singlepart SMS
Dec  1 16:33:19 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug> Added received SMS at '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SMS/3'



Dec  1 16:33:20 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug> (ttyACM2): <-- '<CR><LF><CR><LF>$GPGGA,153320.000,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*4E<CR><LF>$GNGGA,153320.000,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*50<CR><LF>$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E<CR><LF>$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1*1D<CR><LF>$GPGSV,1,1,01,15,,,30,1*62<CR><LF>$GPRMC,153320.000,V,,,,,,,011219,,,N,V*3B<CR><LF>$GNRMC,153320.000,V,,,,,,,011219,,,N,V*25<CR><LF>$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C<CR><LF>$GNVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*32<CR><LF><CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'
Dec  1 16:33:20 dka ModemManager[843]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Sent message...#012<<<<<< RAW:#012<<<<<<   length = 56#012<<<<<<   data   = 03:00:00:00:38:00:00:00:33:00:00:00:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:53:3F:BE:EB:14:FE:44:67:9F:90:33:A2:23:E5:6C:3F:04:00:00:00:01:00:00:00:08:00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:00:00:00
Dec  1 16:33:20 dka ModemManager[843]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Sent message (translated)...#012<<<<<< Header:#012<<<<<<   length      = 56#012<<<<<<   type        = command (0x00000003)#012<<<<<<   transaction = 51#012<<<<<< Fragment header:#012<<<<<<   total   = 1#012<<<<<<   current = 0#012<<<<<< Contents:#012<<<<<<   service = 'sms' (533fbeeb-14fe-4467-9f90-33a223e56c3f)#012<<<<<<   cid     = 'delete' (0x00000004)#012<<<<<<   type    = 'set' (0x00000001)#012<<<<<< Fields:#012<<<<<<   Flag = 'index'#012<<<<<<   MessageIndex = '1'
Dec  1 16:33:20 dka ModemManager[843]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Received message...#012>>>>>> RAW:#012>>>>>>   length = 48#012>>>>>>   data   = 03:00:00:80:30:00:00:00:33:00:00:00:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:53:3F:BE:EB:14:FE:44:67:9F:90:33:A2:23:E5:6C:3F:04:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
Dec  1 16:33:20 dka ModemManager[843]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Received message (translated)...#012>>>>>> Header:#012>>>>>>   length      = 48#012>>>>>>   type        = command-done (0x80000003)#012>>>>>>   transaction = 51#012>>>>>> Fragment header:#012>>>>>>   total   = 1#012>>>>>>   current = 0#012>>>>>> Contents:#012>>>>>>   status error = 'None' (0x00000000)#012>>>>>>   service      = 'sms' (533fbeeb-14fe-4467-9f90-33a223e56c3f)#012>>>>>>   cid          = 'delete' (0x00000004)
Dec  1 16:33:20 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug> Deleted SMS at '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SMS/3'
Dec  1 16:33:21 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug> (ttyACM2): <-- '<CR><LF><CR><LF>$GPGGA,153321.000,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*4F<CR><LF>$GNGGA,153321.000,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*51<CR><LF>$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E<CR><LF>$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1*1D<CR><LF>$GPGSV,1,1,01,15,,,30,1*62<CR><LF>$GPRMC,153321.000,V,,,,,,,011219,,,N,V*3A<CR><LF>$GNRMC,153321.000,V,,,,,,,011219,,,N,V*24<CR><LF>$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C<CR><LF>$GNVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*32<CR><LF><CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'
Dec  1 16:33:22 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug> (ttyACM2): <-- '<CR><LF><CR><LF>$GPGGA,153322.000,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*4C<CR><LF>$GNGGA,153322.000,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*52<CR><LF>$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E<CR><LF>$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1*1D<CR><LF>$GPGSV,1,1,01,15,,,31,1*63<CR><LF>$GPRMC,153322.000,V,,,,,,,011219,,,N,V*39<CR><LF>$GNRMC,153322.000,V,,,,,,,011219,,,N,V*27<CR><LF>$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C<CR><LF>$GNVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*32<CR><LF><CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'
Dec  1 16:33:23 dka ModemManager[843]: <debug> (ttyACM2): <-- '<CR><LF><CR><LF>$GPGGA,15332
```

It says : that the command is `message-store-status`, how can I see the `mmcli` command?

Related issue:

- https://linuxonly.ru/forum/modem-manager-gui/99/how-to-send-sms-from-command-line/
- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mobile-broadband/ModemManager/issues/162

Answer (score -1):

**1.**  The simplest way is to send a plaintext email of no more than 160 characters from a CLI mail app to the SMS gateway for the addressee's phone provider. For the US carriers, you put your ten digit mobile number in front of:

```
Aio Wireless            @mms.aiowireless.net
AirFire Mobile          @sms.airfiremobile.com
Alaska Communications   @msg.acsalaska.com
Alltel (Allied Wirels)  @mms.alltelwireless.com
Ameritech               @paging.acswireless.com
Assurance Wireless      @vmobl.com
AT&T Enterprise Paging  @page.att.net
AT&T Mobility           @mms.att.net
BellSouth               @bellsouth.cl
Bluegrass Cellular      @mms.myblueworks.com
Bluesky Comm (Samoa)    @psms.bluesky.as
Boost mobile            @myboostmobile.com
C Spire Wireless        @cspire1.com
CellCom                 @cellcom.quiktxt.com
Cellular South          @csouth1.com
Centennial Wireless     @cwemail.com
Chariton Valley Wirels  @sms.cvalley.net
Chat Mobility           @mail.msgsender.com
Cincinnati Bell         @mms.gocbw.com
Cleartalk               @sms.cleartalk.us
Cricket                 @mms.mycricket.com
DTC                     @sms.advantagecell.net
Edge Wireless           @sms.edgewireless.com
Element Mobile          @SMS.elementmobile.net
General Comms., Inc.    @mobile.gci.net
Golden State Cellular   @gscsms.com
Greatcall               @vtxt.com
Hawaiian Telcom         @hawaii.sprintpcs.com
I-wireless(Sprint PCS)  @iwirelesshometext.com
I-wireless(T-Mobile)    .iws@iwspcs.net
Kajeet                  @mobile.kajeet.net
LongLines               @text.longlines.com
MetroPCS                @mymetropcs.com
Nextech                 @sms.ntwls.net
Page Plus (Verizon)     @vzwpix.com
Pioneer Cellular        @zsend.com
Pocket Wireless         @sms.pocket.com
Qwest Wireless          @qwestmp.com
Red Pocket Mobile       @vtext.com
Rogers Wireless         @mms.rogers.com
Simple Mobile           @smtext.com
South Central Comms     @rinasms.com
Southernlinc            @page.southernlinc.com
Sprint                  @pm.sprint.com
Straight Talk ATT:      @mms.att.net
Straight Talk Other:    @mmst5.tracfone.com
Straight Talk Sprint:   @tracfone.plspictures.com
Straight Talk T-Mobile: @tmomail.net
Straight Talk Verizon:  @vzwpix.com
Syringa Wireless        @rinasms.com
Teleflip                @teleflip.com
Telus Mobility          @mms.telusmobility.com
Ting                    @message.ting.com
T-Mobile                @tmomail.net
TracFone (prepaid)      @mmst5.tracfone.com
Unicel                  @utext.com
Union Wireless          @union-tel.com
US Cellular             @mms.uscc.net
USA Mobility            @usamobility.net
Verizon Wireless        @vzwpix.com
Viaero                  @mmsviaero.com
Virgin Mobile           @vmpix.com
Voyager Mobile          @text.voyagermobile.com
West Central Wirels     @sms.wcc.net
XIT Communications      @sms.xit.net
```

https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17056/~/list-of-mobile-carrier-gateway-addresses lists other nations' carriers.

If you can't find the gateway address for the addressee's provider, you can do a lookup at https://freecarrierlookup.com .

If you do not have a text based email app (such as [sup](https://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/1/SUP/), [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/), [notmuch](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/notmuch/notmuch.1.en.html), [alpine](https://linux.die.net/man/1/alpine), or [aerc](https://aerc-mail.org/)), see this article on how to send with [curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722556/using-curl-to-send-email).

**2.** The [TextMagic API](https://docs.textmagic.com/) also provides access to SMS from your commend line.

**3.** [Other methods are described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104017/how-can-i-send-mobile-text-message-from-terminal).

**4.** You can use AT commands to send a message following the [specifications in this document](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/127000_127099/127007/10.03.00_60/ts_127007v100300p.pdf).

Comment: How can I send an SMS from command line?

Comment: My carrier is not in the list. FREE MOBILE. can't I do like a normal user using just the cell phone ?

Comment: I have checked all of them and none of them help me send a SMS using a phone number from command line just using my WWAN card.

Comment: I want to try with the carrier destination address FREE MOBILE and I can't find it. Why the hell do I need that, I want to send using the phone number, just as in modem manager gui! It's like if you can now what number is what carrier, it's just too much pain while I want to have the same user experience as a GSM user sending an SMS

Comment: Have you heard about `gammu` I am fighting to get it read into my device

Comment: Did https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=wammu work for you?

Comment: Suggest you call for FREE MOBILE technical and commercial assistance to ask for the address of their email->SMS gateway: 32 44 from a mobile phone or  +33 1 78 56 95 60

Comment: I will not call FREE MOBILE because I can't call evey technical assistance in the world for every of my receiver. I want to use it as a normal caller....  https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gammu  , but I keep having issue with permissions when trying to use it : `gammu info` => `Can not open specified file.`

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa Look at this Stack Overflow answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/40363564

Comment: I have opened an issue on modem-manager because mmcli fail to send sms. Gammu can't communicate with device it says it seems disconnected. I have not found yet...